# Firebase Firestore collectionGroup() query method not recognized - swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build out a collection group query. 
It is for the iOS swift environment. I have the latest Xcode, Swift, firebase, and firestore all running on my machine.

When I try to create a collection group query, the compiler does not offer the collectionGroup() method and throws an error as unrecognized when I type it out myself.

Any else running into this?
Help please?

I wonder if I skipped a step in terminal, but I have followed all google provided documentation to the letter.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  here is the relevant code in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FindYourAcademyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameSearchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationSearchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pleaseFindAcademyLabelOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchResultsTableViewOutlet: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButtonOutlet: DesignableButton!

    var db: Firestore!   

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameSearchTextField.delegate = self
        locationSearchTextField.delegate = self

        searchResultsTableViewOutlet.isHidden = true
        searchResultsTableViewOutlet.delegate = self
        searchResultsTableViewOutlet.dataSource = self

        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()
    }
}
```

// MARK: - UITextField Delegate methods and Keyboard handling

```
extension FindYourAcademyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

        // UITextField Delegate methods
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            if textField == nameSearchTextField {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
                locationSearchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                print("Next button tapped")

            } else if textField == locationSearchTextField {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
                print("Search button tapped")

                isSearching = false

                // keyboard search button fires off the firestore query and returns the query search results

                db.collectionGroup()  /* <-- THIS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN */

            }

            return true
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which version of the Firestore SDK are you using?  Are you sure you have the latest?  Where exactly are you typing that you expect collecitonGroup to appear as an option?  Showing code is always helpful.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the reply.  I know I would show code, but it’s all so basic that my explanation seems all I can do. That’s why it’s so perplexing. I am running firestore 7.2.2. I did a fresh round of upgrades and installs after checking all the relevant firestore and firebase versions I could think of.

Comment: Let me edit my post to include some code.

Comment: You're trying to reference the class var db in an extension that is not part of the class and the code inside the extension is not aware of what db is.

Comment: Hi jay thanks!  I tried that very solution to no luck. The errors were all the same.

Comment: I needed to run a pod update in addition to a pod install. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

i ran a pod update and the issue was resolved, so lesson learned, be sure to update those pods in addition to installing the desired ones!